# Terraform: Create new resources without removing existing (Kubernetes pod)

Tags: terraform, pipeline, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following issue at hand:

Me and my team are creating an AWS EKS cluster using Terraform and we need to be able to start new pods (services) inside the cluster without replacing existing ones.

The idea is to have a separate git repository holding a single .tfvars file and each time someone clones it and pushes a new branch with its edited version, Terraform should create and start a new Kubernetes pod with the updated properties + create an associated SQS queue.

The things is whether I’m passing the variables directly to a resource or using a module I end up with a block with different properties, but the same name, since it can’t be changed dynamically, and the original resource is updated rather than a new one being created.

resource “kubernetes_deployment” “service” {…

One possible solution I thought of is using Terraform Cloud and separating the main config repo and the .tfvars repo into different workspaces where an update and pushing of a new branch of any of the two would trigger a run.

But separate workspaces would mean separate state files, correct? So maybe using a shared state between workspaces could solve it.

I’m quite new to Terraform and have been scratching my head of the problem for a few days now, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add Terraform code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

First off: Terraform might not be the tool for your use case, but this is an interesting problem. More frequently, a full list of services will be managed, to take advantage of terraform's ability to only update the diff between code/config and existing resources.

Terraform wants to manage the resources it creates, and it thinks a terraform path uniquely matches that resource. For your use case, you want to make sure each service has a unique path. That can be done with a `for_each` over a list of one.

I can't tell from the question how your object is structured, so I'll assume you're passing in an object called "service" with a property called `name`:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "service" {
  for_each = [var.service.name]
  ...
}
```

Now, instead of every service being at the path `kubernetes_deployment.service`, the resource is at the path `kubernetes_deployment.service["my_service_name"]`, where the name is what was passed in.

The next part in the process is to change how you invoke terraform. Terraform uses the `-target` flag to only update a resource at a particular path. Assuming you have the name of the service in an environment variable called SERVICE_NAME, you can use this command:

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -target="kubernetes_deployment.service[\"$SERVICE_NAME\"]"
```

That will instruct terraform to only update that path - as long as it matches a valid path in your terraform code, and doesn't ambiguously point to an existing resource, the service will be updated and existing resources won't be touched.

Again, if you have the opportunity to hold on to a full list of services, do that instead. Keeping a full list is much closer to the intended use case for terraform.